# Client/server event handling: alternatives to UdpClient?

Tags: c#, events, udp, remoting

My Winforms client/server application relies on UDP multicast to update all clients in real time. The server fires events into a known UDP sink, and each client receives them, both using instances of the System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient class.

This works great -- when it works. Each client has a remoting object on which it makes its synchronous calls, via TCP, and UDP handles the asynchronous stuff, so the client remains stateless. But many of our clients have UDP disabled in various ways -- some disable multicasting, some disable UDP altogether, some have it disabled on purpose, others by accident. I end up doing a lot more network administration than I would like.

The other choice, it seems to me, is for the server to manage client connections and send the events over TCP, but this requires a stateful server and does not seem very attractive. Are there superior alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using WCF and the publish/subscribe design pattern.  I moved a winforms TCP/UDP app much like you described to WCF using netTCP binding and a UDP broadcast for the clients to find the server, once they find it, they subscribe and you use WCF callback contracts to update the clients.  You'll need to have intelligence on both sides if a connection is dropped.

Also in your case if the server is always a set address with WCF callbacks you wouldn't need to use UDP to find the server, so you could eliminate UDP and just rely on the netTCPBinding to push messages to clients and vice versa.